# Cleanest way to write if statement

Tags: ios, if-statement

I have a if statement that I think is unclean and not well written. I have a value that decreases and changes the scale of a node dependant on the value. So if the value is 95 the scale would be 0.95.

What is the best way to write this? I have been racking my brain trying to think of the best way to do this.

I am doing it currently

```
//Set Stamina
if(hungerInt >= 100){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 1.0f;

} else if (hungerInt >=95){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.95f;

} else if (hungerInt >=90){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.90f;

} else if (hungerInt >=80){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.80f;

} else if (hungerInt >=70){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.70f;

} else if (hungerInt >=60){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.60f;

} else if (hungerInt >=50){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.50f;

} else if (hungerInt >=40){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.40f;

} else if (hungerInt >=30){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.30f;

} else if (hungerInt >=20){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.20f;

} else if (hungerInt >=10){

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.10f;

} else {

    _foodNode.scaleY = 0.0f;

}
```

Ideally I would like it to scale exaclty dependant on the value so if it was `96` it would be 0`.96` or if it was `51` it would be `0.51`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `if`s required:

```
_foodNode.scaleY = (CGFloat)hungerInt / 100.0f;
```

Although this only works if you can guarantee that `hungerInt` is between `0` and `100`, so you might want to check that first

```
if (hungerInt < 0)
    hungerInt = 0;
else if (hungerInt > 100)
    hungerInt = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use ?

```
_foodNode.scaleY = hungerInt / 100.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `_foodNode.scaleY` to go over 1.0 and under 0.0 then you can use this code

```
_foodNode.scaleY = MAX( 0, MIN( (CGFloat)hungerInt / 100.0, 0 ) );
```

Or you can use a function to do it.

```
// some pseudo c code. 
static CGFloat minMax(CGFloat n) {
    return MAX(0, min(100, n));
}
```

and then call it like so:

```
_foodNode.scaleY = minMax((CGFloat)hungerInt) / 100.0
```